# RVM and missing (but installed) gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install a RVM on OSX 10.6.7 and start using it to sandbox my development enviorments on a per project basis but am having some issues.

I have RVM installed and have created a gemset for Rails 2.3.11 and have made sure all the needed gems are installed with gem list:

```
actionmailer (2.3.11)
actionpack (2.3.11)
activemodel (3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.7, 2.3.11)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (3.0.7, 2.3.11)
acts_as_commentable (3.0.1)
ajaxful_rating (2.2.8.2)
arel (2.0.9)
authlogic (3.0.2)
builder (2.1.2)
geokit (1.5.0)
i18n (0.5.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.8.7)
rbbcode (0.1.11)
sanitize-url (0.1.4)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
```

But when I start the server (script/server) I get the following error:

```
Missing these required gems:   
authlogic  

You're running:    
ruby 1.8.7.334 at /Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby 
rubygems 1.6.2 at /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334, /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Running rake gems:install doesn't seem to help.
'which' gives me the following paths:

```
which ruby         
/Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby 
which gem 
/Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/gem
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I figured it out!

There is a new version of authlogic that is only compatible with rails 3.  Since the new rvm gemset needed to install authlogic it just grabbed the most current version available.  To fix I just needed to include the correct version for rails 2 in my environment.rb file:

```
config.gem "authlogic", :version => '2.1.6'
```

The error message was kind of misleading in this case.  Gem was installed just not a version supported by rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

Same shell session? RVM can trip you up because you can use different gemsets/rubies in different shell sessions in the same directory, so if you run the server in a tab/window/session other than the one you're running `which` in, it might not be accurate.

Also, if you're using `.rvmrc` note that it is only loaded when you actually `cd` into the directory, and then only for the current shell session. If you have another session open when creating `.rvmrc`, it won't automatically apply for that session.

Comment: Yup same shell session... The first thing I did after the server errored out was to run which and check the paths...  havent gotten to .rvmrc yet, just want to get the gemset working first.